# Marklogic Additional Query and Searchable expression issue

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I have both `searchable-expression` and `additional-query` in my options file.. In my `additional-query` I have `cts-field-value-query` and when I have this, I get empty results, even though I know that there are documents that match both `searchable-expression` and `additional-query`.. when I take out the `cts:field-value-query` the results come as expected.. I am including the options file and the `xdmp:query-plan`.. I am not understanding why the issue

```
let $options :=
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <additional-query>
         <cts:and-query xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
            <cts:collection-query>
                <cts:uri>OncoWatch</cts:uri>
            </cts:collection-query>
             <cts:field-value-query>
                <cts:field>wos_doctype</cts:field>
                <cts:text>Article</cts:text>
                <cts:text>Review</cts:text>
            </cts:field-value-query>
        </cts:and-query>
    </additional-query>
    <searchable-expression xmlns:es="http://marklogic.com/entity-services"
                           xmlns:wos_dps="http://clarivate.com/schema/wok5.27/public/FullRecord">
      /es:envelope/es:raw/wos_dps:REC/wos_dps:static_data/wos_dps:summary/wos_dps:titles/wos_dps:title
    </searchable-expression>
    <term>
        <term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>
        <term-option>punctuation-insensitive</term-option>
        <term-option>whitespace-insensitive</term-option>
        <term-option>wildcarded</term-option>
    </term>
    <return-plan>true</return-plan>
</options>

let $q := '"pancreatic cancer"'


return
search:search($q, $options)
```

The xdmp plan looks like this

```
    <search:response snippet-format="snippet" total="0" start="1" page-length="10" xmlns:search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
  <search:plan>
    <qry:query-plan xmlns:qry="http://marklogic.com/cts/query">
      <qry:expr-trace>impl:apply-search(map:map(&lt;map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../&gt;), "xdmp:plan", fn:false())</qry:expr-trace>
      <qry:info-trace>Analyzing path for search: fn:collection()/es:envelope/es:raw/wos_dps:REC/wos_dps:static_data/wos_dps:summary/wos_dps:titles/wos_dps:title</qry:info-trace>
      <qry:info-trace>Step 1 is searchable: fn:collection()</qry:info-trace>
      <qry:info-trace>Step 2 is searchable: es:envelope</qry:info-trace>
      <qry:info-trace>Step 3 is searchable: es:raw</qry:info-trace>
      <qry:info-trace>Step 4 is searchable: wos_dps:REC</qry:info-trace>
      <qry:info-trace>Step 5 is searchable: wos_dps:static_data</qry:info-trace>
      <qry:info-trace>Step 6 is searchable: wos_dps:summary</qry:info-trace>
      <qry:info-trace>Step 7 is searchable: wos_dps:titles</qry:info-trace>
      <qry:info-trace>Step 8 is searchable: wos_dps:title</qry:info-trace>
      <qry:info-trace>Path is fully searchable.</qry:info-trace>
      <qry:info-trace>Gathering constraints.</qry:info-trace>
      <qry:info-trace>Search query contributed 3 constraints: cts:and-query((cts:word-query("pancreatic cancer", ("case-insensitive","punctuation-insensitive","whitespace-insensitive","wildcarded","lang=en"), 1), cts:collection-query("OncoWatch"), cts:field-value-query("wos_doctype", ("Article", "Review"), ("lang=en"), 1)), ())</qry:info-trace>
      <qry:partial-plan>
    <qry:term-query weight="1">
      <qry:key>17396426271722676659</qry:key>
    </qry:term-query>
      </qry:partial-plan>
      <qry:partial-plan>
    <qry:term-query weight="0">
      <qry:key>16172058720999549713</qry:key>
      <qry:annotation>collection(OncoWatch)</qry:annotation>
    </qry:term-query>
      </qry:partial-plan>
      <qry:partial-plan>
    <qry:or-two-queries>
      <qry:term-query weight="1">
        <qry:key>8492163112599871394</qry:key>
      </qry:term-query>
      <qry:term-query weight="1">
        <qry:key>10427204889894421302</qry:key>
      </qry:term-query>
    </qry:or-two-queries>
      </qry:partial-plan>
      <qry:info-trace>Executing search.</qry:info-trace>
      <qry:ordering/>
      <qry:final-plan>
    <qry:and-query>
      <qry:term-query weight="0">
        <qry:key>3030157765137304984</qry:key>
        <qry:annotation>descendant(doc-root(element(es:envelope),doc-kind(document)))</qry:annotation>
      </qry:term-query>
      <qry:term-query weight="0">
        <qry:key>14623301529635238289</qry:key>
        <qry:annotation>descendant(element-child(es:envelope/es:raw))</qry:annotation>
      </qry:term-query>
      <qry:term-query weight="0">
        <qry:key>2513953156802156363</qry:key>
        <qry:annotation>descendant(element-child(es:raw/wos_dps:REC))</qry:annotation>
      </qry:term-query>
      <qry:term-query weight="0">
        <qry:key>15620627614067983352</qry:key>
        <qry:annotation>descendant(element-child(wos_dps:REC/wos_dps:static_data))</qry:annotation>
      </qry:term-query>
      <qry:term-query weight="0">
        <qry:key>14267880419025656818</qry:key>
        <qry:annotation>descendant(element-child(wos_dps:static_data/wos_dps:summary))</qry:annotation>
      </qry:term-query>
      <qry:term-query weight="0">
        <qry:key>1256980818223445232</qry:key>
        <qry:annotation>descendant(element-child(wos_dps:summary/wos_dps:titles))</qry:annotation>
      </qry:term-query>
      <qry:or-two-queries>
        <qry:term-query weight="0">
          <qry:key>7002325115516888131</qry:key>
          <qry:annotation>element-child(wos_dps:titles/wos_dps:title)</qry:annotation>
        </qry:term-query>
        <qry:term-query weight="0">
          <qry:key>14914226620346018347</qry:key>
          <qry:annotation>link-child(descendant(element-child(wos_dps:titles/wos_dps:title)))</qry:annotation>
        </qry:term-query>
      </qry:or-two-queries>
      <qry:term-query weight="1">
        <qry:key>17396426271722676659</qry:key>
      </qry:term-query>
      <qry:term-query weight="0">
        <qry:key>16172058720999549713</qry:key>
        <qry:annotation>collection(OncoWatch)</qry:annotation>
      </qry:term-query>
      <qry:or-two-queries>
        <qry:term-query weight="1">
          <qry:key>8492163112599871394</qry:key>
        </qry:term-query>
        <qry:term-query weight="1">
          <qry:key>10427204889894421302</qry:key>
        </qry:term-query>
      </qry:or-two-queries>
    </qry:and-query>
      </qry:final-plan>
      <qry:info-trace>Selected 1264 fragments to filter</qry:info-trace>
      <qry:result estimate="1264"/>
    </qry:query-plan>
  </search:plan>
  <search:qtext>"pancreatic cancer"</search:qtext>
  <search:metrics>
    <search:query-resolution-time>PT0.183458S</search:query-resolution-time>
    <search:total-time>PT0.186923S</search:total-time>
  </search:metrics>
</search:response>
```

And here is the plan when I take out the `cts:field-value-query`

```
<search:plan xmlns:search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
  <qry:query-plan xmlns:qry="http://marklogic.com/cts/query">
    <qry:expr-trace>impl:apply-search(map:map(&lt;map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../&gt;), "xdmp:plan", fn:false())</qry:expr-trace>
    <qry:info-trace>Analyzing path for search: fn:collection()/es:envelope/es:raw/wos_dps:REC/wos_dps:static_data/wos_dps:summary/wos_dps:titles/wos_dps:title</qry:info-trace>
    <qry:info-trace>Step 1 is searchable: fn:collection()</qry:info-trace>
    <qry:info-trace>Step 2 is searchable: es:envelope</qry:info-trace>
    <qry:info-trace>Step 3 is searchable: es:raw</qry:info-trace>
    <qry:info-trace>Step 4 is searchable: wos_dps:REC</qry:info-trace>
    <qry:info-trace>Step 5 is searchable: wos_dps:static_data</qry:info-trace>
    <qry:info-trace>Step 6 is searchable: wos_dps:summary</qry:info-trace>
    <qry:info-trace>Step 7 is searchable: wos_dps:titles</qry:info-trace>
    <qry:info-trace>Step 8 is searchable: wos_dps:title</qry:info-trace>
    <qry:info-trace>Path is fully searchable.</qry:info-trace>
    <qry:info-trace>Gathering constraints.</qry:info-trace>
    <qry:info-trace>Search query contributed 2 constraints: cts:and-query((cts:word-query("pancreatic cancer", ("case-insensitive","punctuation-insensitive","whitespace-insensitive","wildcarded","lang=en"), 1), cts:collection-query("OncoWatch")), ())</qry:info-trace>
    <qry:partial-plan>
      <qry:term-query weight="1">
    <qry:key>17396426271722676659</qry:key>
      </qry:term-query>
    </qry:partial-plan>
    <qry:partial-plan>
      <qry:term-query weight="0">
    <qry:key>16172058720999549713</qry:key>
    <qry:annotation>collection(OncoWatch)</qry:annotation>
      </qry:term-query>
    </qry:partial-plan>
    <qry:info-trace>Executing search.</qry:info-trace>
    <qry:ordering/>
    <qry:final-plan>
      <qry:and-query>
    <qry:term-query weight="0">
      <qry:key>3030157765137304984</qry:key>
      <qry:annotation>descendant(doc-root(element(es:envelope),doc-kind(document)))</qry:annotation>
    </qry:term-query>
    <qry:term-query weight="0">
      <qry:key>14623301529635238289</qry:key>
      <qry:annotation>descendant(element-child(es:envelope/es:raw))</qry:annotation>
    </qry:term-query>
    <qry:term-query weight="0">
      <qry:key>2513953156802156363</qry:key>
      <qry:annotation>descendant(element-child(es:raw/wos_dps:REC))</qry:annotation>
    </qry:term-query>
    <qry:term-query weight="0">
      <qry:key>15620627614067983352</qry:key>
      <qry:annotation>descendant(element-child(wos_dps:REC/wos_dps:static_data))</qry:annotation>
    </qry:term-query>
    <qry:term-query weight="0">
      <qry:key>14267880419025656818</qry:key>
      <qry:annotation>descendant(element-child(wos_dps:static_data/wos_dps:summary))</qry:annotation>
    </qry:term-query>
    <qry:term-query weight="0">
      <qry:key>1256980818223445232</qry:key>
      <qry:annotation>descendant(element-child(wos_dps:summary/wos_dps:titles))</qry:annotation>
    </qry:term-query>
    <qry:or-two-queries>
      <qry:term-query weight="0">
        <qry:key>7002325115516888131</qry:key>
        <qry:annotation>element-child(wos_dps:titles/wos_dps:title)</qry:annotation>
      </qry:term-query>
      <qry:term-query weight="0">
        <qry:key>14914226620346018347</qry:key>
        <qry:annotation>link-child(descendant(element-child(wos_dps:titles/wos_dps:title)))</qry:annotation>
      </qry:term-query>
    </qry:or-two-queries>
    <qry:term-query weight="1">
      <qry:key>17396426271722676659</qry:key>
    </qry:term-query>
    <qry:term-query weight="0">
      <qry:key>16172058720999549713</qry:key>
      <qry:annotation>collection(OncoWatch)</qry:annotation>
    </qry:term-query>
      </qry:and-query>
    </qry:final-plan>
    <qry:info-trace>Selected 1337 fragments to filter</qry:info-trace>
    <qry:result estimate="1337"/>
  </qry:query-plan>
</search:plan>
```

Comment: What are is the configuration of your field? What happens when you only execute the field-value-query (and nothing else)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query plan shows that in both cases fragments were selected from the indexes, so I think your field-value-query did match something. They are excluded by filtering.

That is probably because of your searchable expression. It points to a very specific element deep inside your envelope, and the values for your field likely come from elements outside that path.

In case you are trying to influence search snippets, I'd recommend using the `transform-results` and `preferred-matches` features instead of the searchable expression. Only using a high level element for searchable expression, like /es:envelope/es:raw, or /es:envelope/es:instance, or simply none at all.

HTH!

Comment: what you r saying is, if I am using `searchable-expression` with `additional-query` then the fields should be inside the `searchable-expression` ? In my case the path to which the fields point is not in the `searchable-expression`, thus the issue ?
  How do I achieve where when a user searches for a string (without constraints), the search needs to be performed in set of xpath's. on top of all the `additional-query` constraints ?

Comment: I'd typically create a field that focusses on the desired paths, and create a field search constraint for that, and then instruct users to prefix the search phrase with name of the constraint + colon.. E.g. `"pancreatic cancer"` becomes `titlefield:"pancreatic cancer"`..

Comment: yeah, I was trying to avoid constraint way of doing, as :) when search ws is used many enterprise apps, it is difficult to enforce app developers to add this constraint to their search string, but when there is no other way to do this, then we have to I suppose

Comment: You could consider adding it programmatically at some stage. You could even consider doing a kind of search expansion where non-prefixed terms get expanded into an or query or the original, and a boost-weighted fielded one.

Comment: While typing the above, I remembered you can also implement custom handling code for non-prefixed terms, maybe that is a good way of doing the kind of expansion I am suggestion. For details see: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_31590

Comment: how can I do search expansion without creating a REST extension ? I am trying to avoid REST extensions. typed in too soon :) I can use `apply` in term option and write custom function..